# how do i put fields beside each other in an embed

Tags: javascript, discord.js

so when i try putting three fields beside each other with inline it looks fine on pc, whereas when i see it on phone its a complete mess. someone help me out as most my users on my server are mobile.

```
const economy = require('@economy')
const discord = require('discord.js')

module.exports = {
  commands: ['leaderboard', 'lb'],
  callback: async (message) => {
    const rankings = await economy.getRankings()
    console.log(rankings)
    let txt = "";
    let txt1 = "";
    let txt2 = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      if (!rankings[i]) break;
        txt += `${i+1}\n`
        txt1 += `‎${rankings[i].points}\n`
        txt2 += `<@${rankings[i].userId}>\n`
      }
      const embed = new discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle('**Leaderboard**')
      .setColor('RANDOM')
      .addField('**Rank**', txt, true)
      .addField('**Points**', txt1, true)
      .addField('**Name**', txt2, true)
      message.channel.send(embed)
  }
}
```

Comment: That's a styling problem, can't you add any CSS ? Like flexbox

Comment: Discord on mobile does not support inline fields.